# ECG cardiac monitoring

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential, instrumentation

How is the signal observed from electrode and electrode impedance is affected if we clean one of the pair of Ag/AgCl cardiac electrode by scraping it with steel wool until it was shiny and bright

Answer (score 2):

An Ag/AgCl electrode is covered in AgCl.  It is not shiny and bright.  If you shine it, you are removing the AgCl coating from the electrode, and changing it from a non-polarizable electrode to a polarizable electrode, incredibly changing its properties, likely to the point of uselessness.